# Update an Eclipse plugin to a development version

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, groovy

How do you update a plug-in from a release version to a development version in Eclipse?

I'm dealing with a problem in the groovy-eclipse plugin that looks like it's fixed in the development version ([this bug](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE-1604)).  When I try to install the plug-in, I get a message saying:

```
Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Groovy-Eclipse plugin 2.7.2.xx-RELEASE-20121219-0800-e37 (org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse 2.7.2.xx-RELEASE-20121219-0800-e37)
    Groovy-Eclipse plugin 2.8.0.xx-20130617-1200-e37 (org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse 2.8.0.xx-20130617-1200-e37)
```

I get this message even after I've followed the instructions [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_remove_a_plug-in?) to uninstall the release version of the plugin under "About Eclipse > Installation Details".

What is the procedure to update it to the development track (ideally keeping the ability to go back to the release once it's updated)?

Update: I get the same error message when I moved every file named *groovy* out of the features/ and plugins/ directories.  (This puzzles me!)

Comment: I recently removed my Groovy plugin (2.7.2) and updated to SNAPSHOT 2.8.0 with no problems at all. This surprises me. It seems like the old version wasn't completely removed.

Comment: % ls plugins/*groovy*                           
zsh: no matches found: plugins/*groovy*
% ls features/*groovy*
zsh: no matches found: features/*groovy* (I moved them to featuresX and pluginsX directories.)  "Update" means "Install new software", right?

Comment: Yep. I removed everything concerning the old Groovy and used the URL for the SNAPSHOT version.

Answer (score 0):

First, I wouldn't recommend that you just delete all groovy files from the plugins and features directories.  This is probably going to muck up your install beyond repair.  In fact, at this point, the easiest thing to do is to just start with a fresh Eclipse install and directly re-install from the snapshot update site.

However, if you are feeling adventurous, you can undelete the groovy plugins and features.  Try installing again and paste the entire error message here.  There is a piece of the error message that you are missing.  The full conflict description is not there.